# How to crop ImageView of drawable in Android

Tags: android, image, drawable, crop

Is there any way to crop `Drawable ImageView` in Android. When I searched in google I found lot of examples to crop camera image or gallery image, but i didn't find any solution for `ImageView` and the source of that image is from my `drawablefolder`.

Please anyone help me to crop drawable image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://androidroadies.blogspot.in/2013/05/crop-image-in-android.html. I already tried this but in this example it only crop the camera image and gallery image but not already displayed iamge.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `createBitmap` for crop and `createScaledBitmap` for scale bitmap.

```
Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, width, height);
```

you can also scale image..

```
mBitmap  = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, width, height, true);
```

Comment: What is the width and height here. I want the image same as default cropping, 

not static cropping. If we give static width and how user can crop?

Comment: I want dynamic cropping like in this example. http://androidroadies.blogspot.in/2013/05/crop-image-in-android.html

Comment: Any example on saving the server image on local folder and crop that image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875114/android-save-image-from-url-onto-sd-card

Comment: I am downloading image into "Myfolder" in sdcard and i want crop that image, any idea about crop image from particular folder not from gallery.

Comment: I searched but everyone gives the same answer like they took images from gallery but not from particular folder

Answer (score 1):

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/image"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" >
</ImageView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use createScaledBitmap? Take a look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/15789801/1342638

Comment: I want to crop the image shown in this example. But the image should be from drawable.

Comment: In the example that I show to you, the Bitmap bmp is also loaded from drawables

Comment: I want to crop the image dynamically not static.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhW7J_yK_yI like this but the image must be from drawable because later i will have an server image to crop.

Comment: I see...Take a look at this tutorial that I found: http://www.londatiga.net/featured-articles/how-to-select-and-crop-image-on-android/

Comment: how to crop image from particular folder in sdcard in android

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the ImageView and override the onTouch method. Alternatively you can attach an onGestureDetector. Based on how you want it to behave use a matrix of transformation to scale or translate the image, loaded from your drawables. Finally enable the drawing cache of the view and use the getDrawingCache() method to obtain what you dynamically set for the ImageView to display.