# How to crop the image using four (x,y) coordinates

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview

In my application ,I am going to crop the image using four (x,y) coordinates and also I need to show the cropped image in another activity screen. For example, In the below image, i want to crop the white layer itself. so any one provide the solution to accomplish this technique in my project.

[image: Example image]

Answer (score 10):

Using an instance of the Bitmap class, you can use the Bitmap.creatBitmap(); method passing the original image x y (for the top left corner) and then width and height.

[see documentation here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

in your original example it would be:

```
Bitmap newBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(oldBitmap,10,20,70,80);
```

---

### Edit

The Bitmap class also allows you to access an array of pixel int's representing color. if you know the shape you want to crop in terms of co-ordinates of each point. you could iterate through the array and set alpha to full on the ones that are outside your shape.

Comment: @ theellipsis, your code is useful for rectangle size crop only,but  actually what i need is to crop the image using four coordinates , the shape is not only for rectangle, it varies  based on the four points(quadrilateral).

Comment: so you would want a diamond shaped crop for example? see edit.

Answer (score 1):

I have already done such functionality in one of my apps. Kindly check the code below on how you can crop the captured image from camera.

```
val bytes = cropImage(capturedBitmap!!, viewBinding.viewFinder, viewBinding.containerOverly)

val croppedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.size)

private fun cropImage(bitmap: Bitmap, containerImage: View, containerOverlay: View): ByteArray {
    val heightOriginal = containerImage.height
    val widthOriginal = containerImage.width
    val heightFrame = containerOverlay.height
    val widthFrame = containerOverlay.width
    val leftFrame = containerOverlay.left
    val topFrame = containerOverlay.top
    val heightReal = bitmap.height
    val widthReal = bitmap.width
    val widthFinal = widthFrame * widthReal / widthOriginal
    val heightFinal = heightFrame * heightReal / heightOriginal
    val leftFinal = leftFrame * widthReal / widthOriginal
    val topFinal = topFrame * heightReal / heightOriginal
    val bitmapFinal = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        bitmap,
        leftFinal, topFinal, widthFinal, heightFinal
    )
    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bitmapFinal.compress(
        Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
        100,
        stream
    ) //100 is the best quality possibe
    return stream.toByteArray()
}
```