# Android camera preview dimensions

Tags: android, android-camera

I have this code for creating a camera preview to scan a QR code but doesn't work:

```
try {
            c = ((Class<? extends Controllo>) getIntent().getExtras().get("ctrl")).newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("Error", e.toString());
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }


        autoFocusHandler = new Handler();
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout)findViewById(com.x720.qrscanner.R.id.cameraPreview);

        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
        Boolean trovatoParam = false;
        int minValWidth = 0;
        int minValHeight = 0;
        for (Camera.Size previewSize: mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes())
        {
            Log.e("SIZE", previewSize.width+" - " +previewSize.height);
            Log.e("SCHERMO", size.y+" - "+size.x);
            if(previewSize.width > minValWidth && previewSize.height > minValHeight && previewSize.width <= size.y && previewSize.height <= size.x) {
                parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
                Log.e("-------------SELEZIONO", previewSize.width+"");
                trovatoParam = true;
                minValWidth = previewSize.width;
                minValHeight = previewSize.height;
            }
        }

        if(trovatoParam == true)
            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);


        /* Instance barcode scanner */
        scanner = new ImageScanner();
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.X_DENSITY, 3);
        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.Y_DENSITY, 3);

        scanner.setConfig(0, Config.ENABLE, 0);
        // only enable QRCODE
        scanner.setConfig(Symbol.QRCODE, Config.ENABLE, 1);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera, previewCb, autoFocusCB);

        preview.addView(mPreview);
```

and this to get che camera:

```
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e){
    }
    return c;
}
```

my problem is that camera preview doesn't fill al the screen but I have a big top border. I'm using a galaxy s8+.
Sorry for bad English

issue image:
[image]

Comment: Can you please provide some images of the issue?

Comment: Check this question too.. it may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462538/android-custom-camera-crop-image-inside-rectangle/41488820?noredirect=1#comment86066959_41488820

Comment: ok i added the image

Comment: put your nlayout xml code, check whether the framelayout is matchparent

Comment: i can't add it now but yess it's matching

Answer (score 0):

1) If your container is with width and height as match parent it will surely fill the screen.
Check whether the framelayout is inside any other layout?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>
```

2) And if you are Using **Relative layout** outside **Frame Layout** please change it to **Linear Layout**

3) Or just try to use **SurfaceView** instead of **FrameLayout**.

Please check and let me know.. Best of Luck..

Comment: i think the problem is in the camera preview size, not in the FrameLayout