# How to capture image inside the overlay in Camera2 API Android?

Tags: android, overlay, crop, android-camera2

[image: Image inside overlay]

I need to capture only the image which is inside the overlay box as shown. I don't need the entire image in the TextureView. I'm new to Android and I couldn't figure out a few solutions that were mentioned to capture just the image inside the rectangular region.
The overlay must be at the center. I tried, but I couldn't achieve it.

I followed this code - [Google Sample-Camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

---

To add overlay, I used the following code:

`activity_camera2_basic_fragment.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.googlecamera2.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/control"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="112dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:background="@color/control_background">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/picture" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:contentDescription="@string/description_info"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_info" />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

I implemented the `onCreateView` like this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera2_basic, container, false);

        linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.surface);
        linearLayout.addView(new Rectangle(getActivity()));
        return view;
    }
```

### EDIT

Rectangle.java

```
package com.example.googlecamera2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.View;

public class Rectangle extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public Rectangle(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6);
        Rect rect = new Rect(120, 100, 620, 900);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint );
    }
}
```

Please suggest how I can get just the cropped image from the overlay region and center the overlay in the preview.

Comment: There seem to be two separate issues: one is how to crop the Jpeg, the second is how to crop the live preview. And there is an easy workaround to both: choose the appropriate zoom-in level for your camera.

Comment: Can you please elaborate some more? I'm new to Android and I don't know how I can achieve what you suggested. My major problem is getting the image from the rectangle. Can you perhaps share a snippet? I'd be grateful!

Comment: I didn't understand why crop the live preview?

Comment: I probably misunderstood the meaning of *center the overlay in the preview*. If you are satisfied with the live preview, then you only need to know how to crop the Jpeg.

Comment: Yes, could you please help me out with the cropping? I have actually hard coded the coordinates of the overlay. It is not centred when device changes.

Comment: OK, now I understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189581/discussion-between-vsk-and-alex-cohn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initally created a bitmap, say, `capturedBitmap`. This is the original bitmap captured by the camera.

`capturedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);`

Then I had to find the exact coordinates of the overlay.

```
// Set the left, top, width and height of the overlay to get that portion of the image.
// Also, rotate the image i.e., rotationMatrix

croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(capturedImage, left, top, cropWidth, cropHeight, rotationMatrix, false);
```

Comment: For detail code on how to calculate the TOP, LEFT, WIDTH & HEIGHT, Kindly check the link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801992/6631601

Answer (score 3):

Assume that you know the `x,y,w,h` of the rectangle relative to the area of the camera preview, which is `0,0,textureWidth,textureHeight`.

You also know, when you receive the Jpeg, the dimensions of the image: `0,0,jpegWidth,jpegHeight`.

Now you need to scale the first into second: the crop area will be

```
x*jpegHeight/textureWidth 
y*jpegWidth/textureHight 
w*jpegHeight/textureWidth 
h*jpegWidth/textureheight
```

Width and height are flipped, because you use portrait configuration: very few Android cameras can produce the portrait Jpeg themselves. Most often, they only set the rotation flag in EXIF header, or even that you must handle in your app.

Comment: Thanks for the crucial suggestion.

Comment: can you elaborate more, please? I took all the values but how will I generate a new scaled bitmap from the above formulas?

Comment: @RiddhiShah see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55121125/192373) here.