# FFMPEG: Position images in video when creating slide show

Tags: android, image, video, ffmpeg, slideshow

I'm using FFMPEG shell utility in an Android app to convert users pictures to video, here's an example command:

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 10  -vcodec mjpeg -i - -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -preset ultrafast slideshow.mp4
```

I used to crop images when the user import it in the app but now I would like to allow the user to reposition the image later, here's an example:

[image]

So the user could drag or zoom the image to position it in the clear area (video ratio).

So using the ffmpeg shell command can I specify the image coordinate for each image and position the image in the video.

Comment: mark the coordinates per your picture of the shader and then use those x,y values in the crop . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789049/crop-a-bitmap-image   output of the is piped to your ffmpeg expression

Comment: Crossposting the [same question](http://superuser.com/questions/1018544/ffmpeg-position-images-in-video-when-making-slide-show) on multiple Stack Exchange sites is discouraged.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I meant to do that, I think two different expert communities could have two different perspective. I solved it now by using Java code to process image in-memory and then pipe it to ffmpeg, However, a power user friend (not a coder, youtuper) pointed me to a command line tool can be used instead. I deleted the super-user question coz I already solved it but I stand by my choice of crossposting.

Comment: See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) and [Is SO/SE crosspost accepted?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255649/is-so-se-crosspost-accepted).

Comment: Thanks, In my opinion it might fall under (from the second link)`It's a rare question that's on topic on multiple sites.` but I respect your perspective and removed the answer from the other site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by processing image in-memory serially, piping it to FFMPEG (command line tool) and then using the same reference to load the next image.  For the UI, I used [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) and stored the info provided by the view to crop the image later.