# Scan Barcodes with ML Kit - Limit detection area

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

I am using Firebase ML kit to read QR codes. Currently, API detects every QR code visible in the camera view.
I need the QR to be processed only when it is visible in a transparent rectangle in the center of the screen.
Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

ML Kit itself does not provide the image cropping function. But if you are using Camera2 or CameraX, you could use the [Image.cropRect()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/Image#setCropRect(android.graphics.Rect)) method to crop the image before sending to ML Kit.

If you are using Camera1, you could also convert it to bitmap, and crop the bitmap like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789049/crop-a-bitmap-image).